# How button can accept events which is under a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

Hi in my app we have a requirement that tableview cells should be editable, means can change order of cells. For this i am using reordercontrol. Along with this reorder control should cover entire cell not only right end. For this i am doing below changes in display cell methods.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        for (UIView * view in cell.subviews)
        {

            if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound)
            {


                // [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

                UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
                [resizedGripView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                [resizedGripView addSubview:view];
                resizedGripView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                resizedGripView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

                [cell.contentView addSubview:resizedGripView];

                CGSize sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
                CGSize transformRatio = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width / view.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height / view.frame.size.height);

                //  Original transform
                CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                // Scale custom view so grip will fill entire cell

                transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height);

                // Move custom view so the grip's top left aligns with the cell's top left

                transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -sizeDifference.width / 2.0, -sizeDifference.height / 2.0);

                [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];


                for(UIImageView* cellGrip in view.subviews)
                {
                    if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                        [cellGrip setImage:nil];
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The cell which i am using is a custom cell and cell looks like below.

[image: Custom cell]

After i did above changes in display cell method. I can able to reorder cells on cell from any where not only from right edge. As we can see there is remove button on cell that is not functional after this change because one view getting added on cell even on button. What ever components available on cell should accept events.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `resizedGripView` to `cell.contentView`, you can write a code to bring other controls to top/front. Try below code:

```
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cell.btnPrice];  
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cell.lblProduct];
```

Replace `btnPrice` and `lblProduct` with your controls.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi milan  thanks for your reply. But it does not work :(

Comment: Hi milan thanks it's a great help. I can make it work thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks :). May i know how much exp do you have in ios app development.